# How do you deal with shared data in stateless grails service

Tags: grails, service, singleton, stateless

I was trying to implement a grails SearchService that indexes certain text and stores it in memory for faster lookup.  In order to store this data, I was trying to use a private static property in the Service to store the data, but the property was randomly resetting values.  After rereading documentation, I realized that this is likely because grails services are supposed to be stateless since the employee the singleton pattern.  Still, not sure I understand how a static variable can vary.  Does the JVM load separate copies of service classes per thread?  Not sure I'm wrapping my head around what's happening.

Nonetheless, now that I know I can't rely on static variables to store application-wide data, what's the best approach to store and access data for use across the application, while keeping synchronization and avoiding races?

---

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method on class [TEXTSTORE] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.
    at SearchService.buildIndex(SearchService.groovy:63)
    at SearchService$_indexAllDomains_closure2.doCall(SearchService.groovy:42)
    at SearchService.indexAllDomains(SearchService.groovy:41)
    at SearchService.$tt__rebuildIndex(SearchService.groovy:48)
    at SearchService.afterPropertiesSet(SearchService.groovy:35)
    ... 4 more

Comment: Um, are you seeing these services being unreliable in production or during development when changes to your code cause the service to reload? I have been using various means of keeping shared state (e.g. lookup or indexed data) within services since Grails 1.x and never seen this happen in production. Not once.

Comment: In development.  The issue is reproduceably occurring if an NPE error is thrown by the service and not explicitly caught (still working out some bugs).  Does the class reload in such a case?

Comment: Classes reload in development if you change them, so that may in fact be the reason you are seeing this. You really should make your service more reliable by hooking into the bean lifecycle and have it repopulate/load it's data when it starts up. Typically having your service implement `org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean` and `afterPropertiesSet()` is a good introduction into doing this.

Comment: Thanks, Josh.  Hadn't considered that and will look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be a bit confused about services in Grails. There is no reason why a service (defaulting to singleton) can't have shared state. It's not uncommon for a service to populate some cached or indexed data when it is created so it can be used by multiple callers.

Most often this is done by implementing the `org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean` interface and making use of the `afterPropertiesSet()` method which is called when the service (Spring bean) has been created in the application context and all dependencies have been resolved.

For example:

```
package com.example

import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean

class MyExampleService implements InitializingBean {
  private List data
  def otherService

  void afterPropertiesSet() {
    data = otherService.doSomethingToFetchData()
  }
  // .. other stuff
}
```

By hooking into the lifecycle of the bean you can be fairly sure that even in development (when your service reloads because you've changed some code) it will still have the data needed.

Comment: Josh, that did help, but I ran into another problem immediately.  I am trying to create the index from some data in the DB.  However, it appears domain objects are not ready for use at the time the service is initiated, and I get the following above.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method on class [TEXTSTORE] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly. at SearchService.buildIndex(SearchService.groovy:63) at SearchService$_indexAllDomains_closure2.doCall(SearchService.groovy:42) at SearchService.indexAllDomains(SearchService.groovy:41) at SearchService.$tt__rebuildIndex(SearchService.groovy:48) at SearchService.afterPropertiesSet(SearchService.groovy:35) ... 4 more

Comment: That seems to be a separate issue all together, related to the way GORM is setup during the application startup and the classloader used. I'd recommend posting a new question regarding this issue since it's not the original issue you were having and is in fact a new issue/question.